# Parsing and extracting field values from XML files

Tags: python, xml

I have a couple of GB of log files in the XML format. What I am interested in is finding the rows with a specific command and extract the user that ordered the command.

Which is to say I want to check a particular field in all rows for a specific value and then extract an unknown value from another field on the same line. How do I go about doing that? (I've tried turning to documentation and other sources without understanding how it works.)

I currently use Python 2.7.15, but if 3.* is better or easier in any way I'll use that.

Here's an example of a row in a logfile that I'm interested in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IHEYr4>
  <UserAuthenticated>
    <LocalUsername>User1</LocalUsername>
    <Action>Login</Action>
  </UserAuthenticated>
  <Host>192.168.1.15</Host>
  <TimeStamp>2018-01-18T02:31:00</TimeStamp>
</IHEYr4>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you are expecting to get?

Comment: I guess the goal is to extract them and save them in variables to use to write to other files and so on. So sorry, no example.

Comment: Your write "specific" in your question but you don't specify anything. Which elements to you want to find? Which value do you want to check? Which other field do you want to get the value of. Explain us, based on the XML in your question, what output you expect and why.

Comment: I want to check the <Action> tag and see if it is Login, and if so save <LocalUsername> and <Timestamp>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ElementTree`

**Demo:**

```
x = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IHEYr4>
  <UserAuthenticated>
    <LocalUsername>User1</LocalUsername>
    <Action>Login</Action>
  </UserAuthenticated>
  <Host>192.168.1.15</Host>
  <TimeStamp>2018-01-18T02:31:00</TimeStamp>
</IHEYr4>

"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlVal = ET.fromstring(x)
if xmlVal.find("UserAuthenticated/Action").text == 'Login':
    print(xmlVal.find("Host").text, xmlVal.find("TimeStamp").text)
```

**Output:**

```
('192.168.1.15', '2018-01-18T02:31:00')
```